# Select one cell from a range or selectoin

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, I have one row selected. If I want to get a reference (int VBA) to one cell from that selection, how would I do it?

For example, say I have the row

`[A|B|C|D|E|F|G]`

selected, and I want to only get the value E.

I tried things like `selection.columns(5)`, but that didn't quite work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What didn't work about what you tried?  Can you post a more complete example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
Selection.Cells(1)
Selection.Cells(2)
Selection.Cells(5)
Selection.Cells(100)
etc
```

where cells are numbered from left to right and next from top to bottom.